# Regex to find not start and end with dot and allow some special character only not all

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to match a string which is not start and and with (.)dot and allow some special char like underscore(_) in string
i found dot match regex but not able to match special character what i have done

```
preg_match('/^(?![.])(?!.*[.]$).*$/', $str)
```

Not allowed

```
.example
example.
example?ghh. (or some more special char not allowed in string)
```

allowed

```
 exam.pl56e
    exmple_
    _example_
    exam_ple
```

So string will be

```
1. Not start with dot but in the middle can be a dot(.)
2. String Not allow special char (&%$#@) etc. But allow alpha numeric, underscore
3. Not end with dot(.)
```

It's matching start and end dot correctly but i need to improve it to not allow all special character like `(!&%)` etc. Just allow given special character.
Thanks

Comment: What kind of strings do you need to match? Strings like `word` and not `.word` and `word.`?

Comment: After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Give some example of strings .

Comment: And what do you mean by "special character"? Are we meant to guess? After all, what should be so "special" about some characters? I'd say there is no such thing as a "special character", there are only characters, lots of them.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  please check updated

Comment: @JayBlanchard thanks i have improved question sorry for my bad english

Comment: Are you just after [`"~^\w+$~"`](https://regex101.com/r/YnScbw/1)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew where to put this can you please make full regex?

Comment: @RakeshSharma: I have no idea what you mean by "full regex". `preg_match("~^\w+$~", $s)`? The point is that `\w` matches letters and digits *and `_`*, here, one or more times (`+`), and `^` and `$` *anchor* the pattern at the start/end of the string. It just does not allow dots because `\w` does not match a dot.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it's also not allow dot before and after string?

Comment: Are you going to edit the question with more and more examples? Please just formulate the **rules once**, and let know when it is done.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew please check i have added some more example yeah your regex works for alpha and dot

Comment: No idea what the *rules* are, really. Can you just specify: 1) must contain.... 2) should not start or/and end with a dot, 3) ..... Maybe you need [`"~^(?!\.).+$(?<!\.)~"`](https://regex101.com/r/YnScbw/2)? You know, it is a guessing game now. That is why your question will be downvoted further.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew please check updated question

Comment: @RakeshSharma OK, posted an answer with explanations. My answer matches a string with any number of chars. If you replace `*` with `+` it will require at least 1 char in the string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

```
'~^(?!\.)[\w.]*$(?<!\.)~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YnScbw/3)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!\.)` - a `.` cannot be the first char
- `[\w.]*`  - 0 or more letters, digits, `_` or `.` chars (replace `*` with `+` to match at least 1 char in the string to disallow an empty string match)
- `$` - end of string
- `(?<!\.)` - last char cannot be `.`

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
^\w[\w.]*\w$
```

This is matching alphanum or underscore, optional dot in the midle then alphanumeric or underscore.

NB: It matches strings greater or equal to 2 characters.

This one matches strings with at least one character long.

```
^(?!\.)[\w.]+$(?<!\.)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('/^[^.].*[^.]$/', $str)
```

if you need to avoid dot from a beginning and end of the string you want use the class   [^.]

The  .* tels you that you allow all chars in a string. If your goal is to restrict some chars inside a string you can use [^......] before dot.

```
preg_match('/^[^.][^?*].*[^.]$/', $str)
```

Comment: That pattern ignores the "special characters" clause in the question completely...

Comment: underscore is allowed?

Comment: no it's allow all special chars by using dot. if you need screen special characters you need to add [^....] after dot with forbidden chars

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.  A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.